# Hover pseudo-class not working when inserting CSS directly into HTML?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hover

For some reason I can't get the hover state of this div to work for a button I created within a Wordpress page:

```
<div class="signupbutton" style="font-size: 28px; background-color: #5aaf20; color: white; text-align: center; font-family: 'Oswald', Arial, Helvetica; padding: 25px 50px; box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #b7b9b5; margin: 0% 30%;">SIGN-UP</div>

<style> 
div.signupbutton:hover {background-color: #80f133;}
</style>
```

If I replace the hover's property (i.e. to a border) it works fine. What gives?

Answer (score 2):

That's because inline styles override your `:hover` styles. You can learn more about selectors' specificity reading [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity).

Better [separate presentation from content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content) and place inline styles in the stylesheet:

```
div.signupbutton {
    font-size: 28px;
    background-color: #5aaf20;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Oswald', Arial, Helvetica;
    padding: 25px 50px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #b7b9b5;
    margin: 0% 30%;
}
div.signupbutton:hover {
    background-color: #80f133;
}
```

Comment: I started adding an answer, but Oriol's is presented much better than mine was so I +1'd his instead.

Comment: I thought so.

What's the easiest way to do this with a Wordpress page?

Comment: @naturligt Not sure since I don't have Wordpress. But just add the code where you used your `:hover` rule.

Answer (score 0):

The example below works, but the way that @Oriol did is better.

```
div.signupbutton:hover {background-color: #80f133 !important;}
```

Comment: @naturligt In your case you can use "!important" but if you have a big application, you can do it otherwise... to become more organized.